# Isapi Rewrite: from www to non-www and at the same time from http to https

Tags: isapi-rewrite

i have tried it all!

this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

works only if i don't put the http at the beggining

how do make that to work:
if there is http redirect to https
if there is www redirect to non-www
and ofcourse both on the same time

```
http://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
www.domain.com --> https://domain.com
http://domain.com --> https://domain.com
```

with every subfolders after and query!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you also want

```
https://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
```

Did you ever get this working? I'm having trouble getting a test https site going to double-check this.

In the meantime, I do see a couple things, so try this instead (this assumes isapi_rewrite v3, which it looks like you're using):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [NC,R=301]
```

This adds parentheses to the RewriteRule to capture the url for the $1.

Then the slash between the %1$1 isn't needed, since there's one at the start of the $1 capture.

I like to use NC for not case-sensitive, and the R rule is a final rule, so you don't need the L for last.

**EDIT**

I revisited this answer, to update/clarify a couple of secondary issues in my original answer above. These don't change the main solution above, which was to add the parentheses to do the capture.

Original:

> Then the slash between the %1$1 isn't needed, since there's one at the start of the $1 capture.

This actually depends where the rules are, and whether there's a `RewriteBase` statement. Common shared-host configurations don't have the leading slash here in the rules, so the slash would be needed. If you're not sure, you can try with and without.

Original:

> I like to use NC for not case-sensitive, and the R rule is a final rule, so you don't need the L for last.

It turns out it is useful to have L with R for performance, as `[NC,R=301,L]`. I had actually asked this at Helicon Tech a year before this question, but had forgetten it:
 http://www.helicontech.com/forum/14826-Does_Redirect_need_Last.html
From their response:

> ... the reason for us to use [L] in 301 redirect rules is that redirect occurs not that 
>   immediately. Even though the rule is matched futher rules will be proccessed (run through), unless you have [L]....